Horror film from the 60's that ends with the protagonist kissing a woman, who becomes a rotten corpse
It may have been a Vincent Price movie. At the end of the movie, the protagonist embraces and kisses a woman. He then pulls away from her and sees that she has become a rotting corpse.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there anything else at all you can recall?  Was it colour or black-and-white?  Where did you see it?

Stanley Kubrick's The Shining is rather later than the 60s, but has exactly such as scene.
https://theshining.fandom.com/wiki/Lorraine_Massey

There was one of the versions of Lost Horizon that had a scene like that ...Conway leaves the valley of Shangri-la taking Maria with him, he embraces her as they step outside, but then she ages to a 140 year old corpse in a few seconds

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

It could be The Terror though the film stars Boris Karloff and Jack Nicholson (not Price).  It was made in 1963 and the final scene has the girl turning into a rotting corpse.

Film queued to the kiss and her rotting away




Can you provide a screenshot?

Thank you!  Yes; The Terror. I saw it when I was a kid and always remembered that scene. It was similar to a scene from The Magic Sword -- a kiss changes a pretty girl into a laughing old witch. Ha! Thanks again.

Did she have a spell cast which preserved youth and beauty?
